# Generate URL inside a Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Is there a way to generate URL inside a controller? I want to do the following inside a controller instead of a view.

`<% =Url.Action("Validate", "Home", New With {.ValidID = ID})%>`

Comment: Cannot select both so selected the first one , thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the "Bee-stings."

Something like:

```
url = Url.Action("Validate", "Home", New With {.ValidID = ID})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as your controller inherits from Controller (which it must in order to work as an MVC controller), you can use the same syntax without the <%= %>.

```
Dim url = Url.Action("myAction", "myController", New With { ... })
```

alternatively if you reference the MVCContrib DLL, you will have access to strongly typed helpers, and be able to do something like:

```
Dim url = Url.Action(Of myController)(function(a) a.myAction(ID))
```

my VB coding days are dated, so forgive me if the syntax is a bit fudged